# Sails js and Sequelize, no associations added to database

Tags: postgresql, associations, sails.js, sequelize.js

This is how my models are structured in sails:

```
myapp
--api
----controllers
----models
-----User.js
------Role.js
```

User.js

```
module.exports = {
 attributes:{
   id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
   },
   username: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
   },
   password: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
   }
 },
 associations: function() {
   User.hasOne(Role, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'role' });
 }
};
```

Role.js

```
module.exports = {
 attributes:{
   id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
   },
   name: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
   }
 }
};
```

After sails lift, in the postgresql I have users table with id, username, password, createdat and updatedat + roles table with id, name, createdat and updatedat. No foreignKey for Roles in Users table.

How I can fix this?
I'm using sails-hook-sequelize and sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints, can this occur because of them?

Thanks!

## Edit:

The correct way was:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes:{
   id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
   },
   username: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
   },
   password: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
   }
 },
 associations: function() {
     User.hasOne(Role, {
      as : 'role',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'roleId',
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns are added by default unless you set the `timestamps` option to false.  See the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/).

To add foreign key constraints, you need to define [associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/) for the Roles model.